# Android asset-helper extract images from DB

Tags: android, phpmyadmin

I'm using android-asset-helper. I'm trying to items from a database. One of the field is a blob field, which contains a image. I've tried exporting the database(from phpmyadmin) with the blob field both as binary and hex. Then i have converted the database to sqllite from the command line and made an archive out of it.

The database is where it's suppose to be and working fine. For example, this call works just fine:

```
String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("id"));
```

I've tried both:

```
byte[] bitmapdata = c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("image")); 
if(bitmapdata != null && bitmapdata.length > 0)
{ 
    ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bitmapdata);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
    item.setBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

and

```
byte[] bitmapdata = c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("image")); 
if(bitmapdata != null && bitmapdata.length > 0)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapdata, 0, bitmapdata.length); 
    item.setBitmap(bitmap); 
}
```

Both of these methods returns null. 
I want to know if you know of any method that works, or will i just have to put the images in the asset folder and use them like that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: decodeByteArray works just fine, make sure your byte array is correct e.g. by logging bitmapdata.length

Comment: It is correct. At least it returns a long array. I've also tried doing the reverse operation (to create the image in phpmyadmin from that string) and it works.

Comment: ok if you have image.png and its size is x bytes on your disk then your byte array should also be x bytes long, verify that

Comment: bitmapdata.length is 159534. The .bin of the image(taken from the server using phpmyadmin) is 156 KB. Does that mean that the image wasn't exported correctly? If so ... how should I do it?

Comment: if your image file size is also 159534. this shold work, basically BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray expects input byte array as if it was taken from external image representation file (.jpg, .png, etc)

Comment: Do you think there is a issue when converting from sql to sqllite?

Comment: I think you're right... i've tried it with a .png image and it works. Seems .bin is not supported. Thanks for the help.